# XRSettings.enabled with Unity 2017.2 and Oculus 1.18.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

The following code snippet returns **False** when you press **x** with the **Virtual Reality Supported** option ticked:

```
public class ToggleXR : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) )
        {
            XRSettings.enabled = !XRSettings.enabled;
            Debug.Log("XRSettings: " + XRSettings.enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for the latest stable releases of **Oculus 1.18.1** and **Unity 2017.2** not allowing VR mode?

Oculus has been silent on this, so I am wondering if everybody working with these two latest versions is having the same problem, or is it just me? Am I missing something that I should download and import into Unity further to checking the **XR Settings** option?

I created a new **Unity 2017.2.0f3** project, enabled **VR** in **XR Settings**, but get the following two errors:

*Couldn't open Assets/OVR/Plugins/1.18.1/OSXUniversal/OVRPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/OVRPlugin, error: dlopen(Assets/OVR/Plugins/1.18.1/OSXUniversal/OVRPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/OVRPlugin, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/LibOVRRT_0.framework/Versions/5/LibOVRRT_0
Referenced from: /Users/OculusUnityProject/Assets/OVR/Plugins/1.18.1/OSXUniversal/OVRPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/OVRPlugin
Reason: image not found*

and

*Oculus Plugin could not be loaded.*

I also downloaded and imported (from the **Asset Store**) **Oculus Integration** (which was automatically updated to **1.18.1**) but still get the exact two errors above.

How do I get a simple basic Unity-VR project running?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading this old, beta and apparently abandoned [runtime](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-runtime-for-os-x/) worked for me.